# How does this Union and Bit field interaction work?

Tags: c++, unions, bit-fields

So here is an example:

```
struct field
{
    unsigned int a : 8;
    unsigned int b : 8;
    unsigned int c : 8;
    unsigned int d : 8;
};

union test
{
    unsigned int raw;
    field bits;
};

int main()
{

    test aUnion;
    aUnion.raw = 0xabcdef;

    printf("a: %x \n", aUnion.bits.a);
    printf("b: %x \n", aUnion.bits.b);
    printf("c: %x \n", aUnion.bits.c);
    printf("d: %x \n", aUnion.bits.d);


    return 0;
}
```

now running this I get:

```
a: ef
b: cd
c: ab
d: 0
```

And I guess I just dont really get whats happening here. So I set raw to a value, and since this is a union, everything else pulls from that since they have all been set to be smaller than an unsigned int? so the bit field is based on raw? but how does that map out? why is d: 0 in this instance?

I would appreciate any help here.

Comment: @Inian Its the struct above the union.

Comment: Got it, may you missed the typedef's but the union needs to be defined as `union test aUnion;` and `bits` as `struct field bits;` - FYI

Comment: The code posted as such doesn't compile

Comment: This was a quick example on my computer, which does compile. May be a compiler difference

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Don't tag both unless you're asking about the differences between them. (As far as I know, your code has undefined behaviour in C++.)

Comment: This example was written in c++

Comment: (anyway, IMO, this is more a C question than a C++ one)

Comment: @molbdnilo What about this has undefined behavior out of curiosity?

Comment: You're only allowed to read the "active" union member, which is (informally) the last one you wrote to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using hexadecimal representation of an integer is useful because it makes clear what is the value of every byte of the integer. So the setting

```
aUnion.raw = 0xabcdef;
```

means that the value of least significant byte is `0xef`, that the second least significant byte has value `0xcd` and so on. But you are setting the `raw` field of the *union*, that is an integer so it is 4 bytes long. In the previous representation the most significant byte is missing, so it can be written as

```
aUnion.raw = 0x00abcdef;
```

(it is like making explicit that an integer `x = 42` has `0` hundreds, `0` thousands and so on).

Your union fields represent respectively `a =byte[0]`, `b = byte[1]`, `c = byte[2]` and `d = byte[3]` of the integer `raw`, since **in a union all the elements share the same memory location**. This is true because you are running your code in a **little endian** architecture (least significant bytes come first).

So:

```
a = byte[0] of raw = 0xef
b = byte[1] of raw = 0xcd
c = byte[2] of raw = 0xab
d = byte[3] of raw = 0x00
```

Comment: Ah okay so because I had set the field of the union to that hex value, pulling the bit field pulls it based on endian and size of each part of the field from first to last. Thank you this pretty much explains what I wanted to know

Answer (score 2):

Its because your `unsigned int` isn't 32 bit long enough (all 32 bits not set) to completely fill all the bit field values. Because it only 24 bits long, the bit field `d` is showing hex value of `00` . Try it for e.g.

```
aUnion.raw = 0xffabcdef;
```

which will produce

```
a: ef 
b: cd 
c: ab 
d: ff
```

Since the `dd` bit field occupies bits 24-32 (on little endian), unless the assigned `unsigned int` field has been assigned a value that occupies those bits set, that bit field position doesn't show the value too.